# How to convert video along with audio in h264 ffmpeg?

Tags: sound, video, ffmpeg, h264

ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --enable-libmfx --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

I know to convert from one format to other format using the commands like,

```
ffmpeg -i M.avi -c:v h264_qsv -look_ahead 0 -strict -2 -preset:v fast M.mp4
```

Now I m in need of doing conversions like M.avi to M.h264 and then from M.h264 to M.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i M.avi -c:v h264_qsv -look_ahead 0 -strict -2 -preset:v fast M.h264

ffmpeg -i M.h264 -c:v h264_qsv -look_ahead 0 -strict -2 -preset:v fast M.mp4
```

While doing this everything worked fine, but M.mp4 is playing without audio.

As per the link,

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725958/ffmpeg-conversion-skips-audio

I even tried with `-acodec copy` as

```
ffmpeg -i M.avi -c:v h264_qsv -look_ahead 0 -strict -2 -preset:v fast -acodec copy M.h264

ffmpeg -i M.h264 -c:v h264_qsv -look_ahead 0 -strict -2 -preset:v fast -acodec copy M.mp4
```

while using the command `ffmpeg -i M.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -look_ahead 0 -strict -2 -preset:v fast -acodec copy n.h264`, the outcome is

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --enable-libmfx --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'M.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2016-01-31 09:44:22
  Duration: 00:03:28.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2120 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1925 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-01-31 09:44:23
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
File 'n.h264' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_32
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[h264 @ 0x2fd4940] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, h264, to 'n.h264':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (h264_qsv), nv12, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1000 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 h264_qsv
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 5001 fps=284 q=-0.0 Lsize=   23221kB time=00:03:28.33 bitrate= 913.1kbits/s speed=11.8x    
video:23221kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

Still no audio. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you pastebin the complete command + full terminal output from one of your failed encodes? Bear in mind as well that saving audio to the output '*.h264' will not work...

Comment: @andrew.46 updated the question. Then in which format can i store my intermediate file other than .h264?

Comment: Why are you performing the unnecessary extra step of .h264 to .mp4? Why not encode directly to .mp4?

Comment: I have already tried encoding directly to .mp4. But anyways I am also interested in this extra step

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to extract the Audio and Video in a single step, but you can easily extract both Audio and Video with a short script.

Assuming the audio is AAC as in your post:

```
#! /bin/bash
###################################################################
i="" # edit with the input avi file name including extension
###################################################################
  ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v h264_qsv -look_ahead 0 -strict -2 -preset:v fast -an "${i%.*}.".h264
  ffmpeg -i "$i" -vn -acodec copy "${i%.*}.".aac
done
```

To recombine them in in an MP4 container, you can do:

```
#! /bin/bash
###################################################################
i="" # edit with the input h264 file name including extension
###################################################################
  ffmpeg -i "$i" -i "${i%.*}.".aac -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${i%.*}.".mp4
done
```

This is not an ideal solution, as it creates an additional step (as noted in the comments).  But at least it would give you a starting point :)

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

.h264 is a raw video container format. It doesn't know about audio. ffmpeg behaves absolute correctly. If you want h264 - you get it. Without audio.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, there is no reason to do this in multiple steps, and h264 format cannot hold audio, so that extra step is where you are losing the audio.

You should also note that you are performing full re-encoding of the video on your second step, which is a waste of time and is a lossy operation (you will lose video quality).

To convert to h264+aac all in one step, do something like this:

`ffmpeg -i M.avi -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac out.mp4`

(The commands I'm giving are in their most basic form. You should still add in your additional flags for quality, etc.)

To convert in multiple steps, you will need to create separate video and audio files, then combine them into a container. To find out what format the avi is using, just run ffmpeg without any flags or output

`ffmpeg -i M.avi`

and it will show you the details of all of the channels in the avi container.

If the formats in the avi container are supported by mp4, you could just pull the video and audio into an mp4 without re-encoding (this would avoid losing quality)

`ffmpeg -i M.avi -c copy M.mp4`

Or you could re-encode them into separate video and audio, then combine

`ffmpeg -i M.avi -c:v h264_qsv M.h264`

`ffmpeg -i M.avi -c:a aac M.aac`

`ffmpeg -i M.h264 -i M.aac -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy M.mp4`

Notice that you should copy codecs in the final step instead of re-encoding.